# Did ros-galactic-example-interfaces break?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like  a new version of ros-galactic-example-interfaces was released today, version 0.9.2-2focal.20220430.122855, or possibly/likely one of its dependencies. And suddenly, my example code in a container (which fetches example-interfaces via rosdep install), no longer works. It produces the following error when I attempt to run it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm my/ros:app
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py”, line 46, in import_type_support
return importlib.import_module(module_name, package=pkg_name)
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/init.py”, line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File “”, line 1014, in _gcd_import
File “”, line 991, in _find_and_load
File “”, line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File “”, line 657, in _load_unlocked
File “”, line 556, in module_from_spec
File “”, line 1166, in create_module
File “”, line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: /opt/ros/galactic/lib/libexample_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.so: undefined symbol: rosidl_runtime_c__double__Sequence__are_equal
```

I'm not sure whom I should inform. I see that a container built from the same Dockerfile a few days ago has version 0.9.2-2focal.20220210.222214 of ros-galactic-example-interfaces and that has been working fine for me all week.

--wpd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400197/did-ros-galactic-example-interfaces-break?/) by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2022-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pepis](https://answers.ros.org/users/66603/pepis/) on 2022-05-06**:
Same problem here :(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-07**:
Looking at [the CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/blob/a3ba794d409d6a0cf7732d23c966fad18a87ed31/CHANGELOG.rst), it's unlikely this is something local to `example_interfaces` (there aren't really any changes to the code itself, just metadata). Github's [diff seems to agree](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/compare/0.9.1...master).

Seeing as `rosidl` is involved, perhaps the problem is there?

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-09**:
And according to [rosidl_generator_c](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/blob/galactic/rosidl_generator_c/CHANGELOG.rst) (the one that seems to be throwing the error) there has been some changes the 28th of April.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-09**:
Yes, agreed. Likely candidate: [ros2/rosidl#648](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/pull/648).

I would suggest a rebuild of the workspace(s) that started failing.

In general there is no ABI-compatibility guarantee, so a rebuild of a workspace you have after an update is *always* recommended.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-09**:
Just a note for the rebuild, go into your workspace and remove `build` `install` and `log` and *then* build again.

**Comment by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on 2022-05-09**:
Rebuilding doesn't work for me... at least, rebuilding the docker container that pulls in the prebuilt Ubuntu .deb files doesn't work for me.
This seems to be a problem with the distributed .deb files.  Who should I inform about this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-09**:
I would not draw any conclusion yet and just report the symptoms you observe on the [rosidl issue tracker](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues).

If it turns out to be an issue elsewhere, the maintainers there will most likely direct you to a more suitable tracker/venue.

Do mention you've already posted on ROS Answers about this in your issue, so discussions remain linked/visible.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-12**:
Seeing as you're using a Docker image: make sure there are no outstanding `apt` updates.

I've seen this problem happen on systems where only *some* packages had been updated, but others were at older versions.

You can check whether there are outstanding updates with `apt update && apt list --upgradable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add `apt update && apt upgrade -y` to the `Dockerfile`.

I was certain that my `Dockerfile` had an `apt update -y` command in it, but the Gremlins snuck in an removed it when I wasn't looking.  This was a false alarm.  Sorry folks.

---

Originally posted by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) with karma: 249 on 2022-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0